# how to fix htmlspecialchars invalid multibyte sequence in argument if data is an ascii type in yii app?

Tags: yii

my data to display is an ascii type based from

`mb_detect_encoding` of PHP, i have tried CHtml::encode($str); when displaying the data, but am getting that invalid multibyte sequence argument, what's the best thing to do with this ?

Comment: Where is the data from? Db, user? Are you sure it is ASCII?

Comment: Did you maybe truncate the string with a function like `substr()`? In this case you could have cut a UTF-8 multibyte character "in half" in which case the above error appears. You should always use the `mb_...` methods when you manipulate unicode strings.

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding` is useless for single-byte encodings; it will **always** "detect" that the input is indeed in the given encoding. Post your code.